# Googlescript Updating timestamp by row

Tags: timestamp

I would like to update the col 26 with the timestamp data with onEdit function,
only if certain column are modified and only if certain column are filed

Problem :
the update is working, but the check if the cell is empty is not completed
the update is done even the cells are empty

thanks for your help

PS: sorry for my poor English

```
    function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var column = range.getColumn();
    var rows = range.getNumRows();
    var date = new Date();

    if(column == 2|| column == 3|| column == 4|| column == 5|| column == 9 && sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValues() !== ''&& sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValues() !== '')
 
 { 
    sheet
    .getRange(row, 26, rows)
    .setValue(date)
    .setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
 }                                                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition in the if function

```
   if( 
   (column == 2|| column == 3|| column == 4|| column == 5|| column == 9) 
   && sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValues() !== '' && sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValues() !== ''&& sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValues() !== '') {
    ... <setTimeshtamp> ...
    }
```

By the way, I recommend making fewer calls to Sheets via .getValue(). It is better to read the whole row once and work with it. Here's how I solved your task

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet(),
      row   = e.range.getRow(),
      col   = e.range.getColumn(),
      date  = new Date(),
      rowData = sheet.getRange(row + ':' + row).getValues()[0],
      chkColumns = [2,3,4,5,9];


  if (chkColumns.some(colNum => colNum==col) &&
      !rowData.some((cell,ind) => cell=='' && chkColumns.some(indCol => indCol==ind+1))){
        sheet.getRange(row,26).setValue(date).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
    }
```

}